# JQuery on click <li> interference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, the problem is a little hard to explain but I'll do my best.

when I click on one `<li>` element everyone else inside him is clicked.

I try to create categories and subcategories.but whenever I click on a category a subcategory is also called!

```html
<li class="has-sub product_type" id="category1"> <a>Lorem1</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="product_sub_type" id="subcategory1"><a>Lorem2</a></li>
        <li class="product_sub_type" id="subcategory2"><a>Lorem2</a></li>
        <li class="product_sub_type" id="subcategory3"><a>Lorem2</a></li>
        <li class="product_sub_type" id="subcategory4"><a>Lorem2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var type_id = '';
    $(".all_products").fadeOut("fast");

    $(".product_type").on("click", function(event) {
        alert("Dbg");
        type_id = event.currentTarget.id;
        $(".big_categoryes").fadeOut("fast");
        $(".all_products").fadeIn("smooth");

        sortProducts(type_id);
    });

    var type_sub_id = '';
    $(".product_sub_type").on("click", function(event) {
        type_sub_id = event.currentTarget.id;
        sortSubProducts(type_sub_id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Call `event.stopPropagation()` in the `.product_sub_type` click event handler

Comment: event bubbling.

Comment: Oh thanks for help Rory! you are awesome!!!!!

Comment: Alternatively set the product type click listener on `$(".product_type >a")`